# load multiple springboot app with annotation in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am having a springboot application to load different classes dynamically based on the user input.

Can someone suggest any better and optimised way for doing this.

**Below is my approach:-**

```
//I have a map of actions available with their respective classes(which is also a springboot app)
private static Map<String,Class> actions = ImmutableMap.<String,Class>builder()
                                                       .put("A",A.class),
                                                       .put("B",B.class);

//main method of springboot root app
public static void main(String args[]){
 new MainApplication().run(args);
}

//get the action class and run that application
public void run(String args){
 Class action = getAction();
 SpringApplication app = new SpringApplicationBuilder(job).build();
 app.run(args);
}

//action.name is passed as an argument while starting the application( for.ex action.name="A")
private Class getAction(){
 String action = System.getProperty("action.name");
 Class classType = actionMap.get(action);
 return classType;
}
```

Now I want to load these action applications with just an annotation.
Can someone suggest any way to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional Bean concept as below

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        value="action.name", 
        havingValue = "a", 
        matchIfMissing = false)
public class TestBeanConditional {

}
```